# Error while updating and installing pod file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoapods

Every time am trying to update the pod file it shows me some errors. For updating the podfile

```
$open -e podfile
```

and I do the changes

then

```
$install podfile
```

the errors

```
install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 file2
   install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
   install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
```

This was not appearing before. It happened only when I tried to create the same pod file
in another project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `pod install` assuming you already have CocoaPods installed. If not you need to install it with `sudo gem install cocoapods`. You can read the getting started guides [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/)

Comment: I did this step before. And I tried to do it now ,nothing work.

Comment: The command you posted in your question isn't part of CocoaPods though.

Comment: You were right. I changed the command to ($ pod install) instead of (install pod file) it worked perfectly. Thanks.